# How to mirror my website for changes

Tags: django

I'm making website for one organization in `Django`. Everything works fine, but every time I wan't to change something, I try it on local "mirror" (all files are copied) of the website and if everything works well, I "push" it to the actual webpage. Sometimes, e.g small templates edits etc. I do on the actual webpage, since It is boring to make new copy.

So my question is: Is there something like github `commit-push` system for developing sites? Something, what would allow me to do one way sync from actual webpage to my (not necessarily local) copy and after trying these changes on this copy I could just "push" to the main (only changed files of course)?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with just using `git`, as described in your question? `rsync` is also a pretty amazing FTP replacement (can't remember the last time I had to use FTP instead of `ssh`/`rsync`) and only copies changed files.

Comment: It looks to me a bit like a lot of work. But with Fabric it looks bearable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It's essentially a wrapper around ssh and an excellent tool for all your deployment needs. With Fabric you write so called "tasks" in Python that do all the repetitive stuff you would normally do in the shell.

To update your production environment against your development environment (or vice versa) some common things to do are:

- ssh into server
- activate virtualenv
- cd to your project directory
- git update
- collect static files
- touch the wsgi file
- copy over some media files (via rsync, sftp or whatever)
- dump or import a database
- ...

Now with Fabric you wrap all this stuff in tasks, that can later be run from your development environment.

It might take a while until you have written and combined all the tasks for your specific environment and needs, but it's very well worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you! 

Edit: Unfortunately, it is only for Python 2. I'm currently on 3.4. But it looks that master should work. Will give it a try.